# Handling file uploads larger than 10mb in PHP

Tags: php, file-upload, web, xampp

I have this form

```
<table class="table">
        <div class="error"><?php if(!empty($errors))echo output_errors($errors);?></div>
        <form action = "upload_music.php" method = "POST" enctype = "multipart/form-data">
        <tr>
            <td>Artist:</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="artist" value=""></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Track Name:</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="track_name" value=""></td>
        </tr><?php print_r($_FILES);?>
        <tr>
            <td>Genre:</td>
            <td>
            <?php  
                $genres = Genre:: getAllGenre();
            ?>
                <select name = "genre">
                    <?php 
                        for($i = 0  ; $i<count($genres);$i++){
                        ?>
                        <option value = "<?php echo "{$i}"?>"><?php echo "{$genres[$i]['genre']}";?> </option>
                    <?php   }

                    ?>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
        </tr>
            <td>Track:</td>
            <td><input type='file' name='file_path'></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>Track Description:</td>
            <td><textarea name="track_desc" rows ="5"></textarea></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input class="btn btn-success" type="submit" name = "submit" value="Upload"></td>
        </tr>
        <form>
    </table>
```

Where the user will have to upload a track. every time I upload a file that is larger than 7mb the `print_r($_FILES);` prints an empty array. but when I upload a file that is below 8mb or an mp3 the `print_r($_FILES);` prints an array with values.

I am guessing that the some  file is not being read by $_FILES  because their size is larger than 8mb?  if that's the case How would I upload files that is larger than 8mb? also my php.ini settings with regards to POSt and FILE uploads looks like this

```
post_max_size = 128M
upload_max_filesize = 128M
```

if you guys needed an extra information I am using XAMPP.

Comment: memory_limit? max_execution_time? max_input_time? No error message?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you are looking into wrong php.ini because the default **post_max_size** is generally 8M.

Restart the web server and look into **phpInfo()**

Answer (score 1):

You can easily just override the ini in your PHP with this code.

```
ini_set('memory_limit', '32M');
ini_set('post_max_size', '16M');
ini_set('upload_max_filesize', '16M');
```

Answer (score 1):

I can't think of a better answer than [this](http://www.sitepoint.com/upload-large-files-in-php/)

I would recommend using the per-script ini_set as you don't necessarily want to raise execution time site wide.